# Mapping <LSGT> + WASD to arrow keys with xkb

Tags: x11, custom-keyboard

I am trying to map <LSGT> + WASD to arrow keys. It means, while holding <LSGT> key, WASD should act like arrow keys.

Here is the configuration I am using so far:

```
default partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "berdan" {

    include "us(basic)"
    name[Group1]= "English (Berdan)";

    // Switch ESC with Caps Lock
    key <CAPS>  {   [  Escape       ]   };
    key <ESC>   {   [ Caps_Lock     ]   };

    // Implement LSGT+WASD as arrow buttons
    include "level5(lsgt_switch)"
    key <AD02> {    [     w, W, Up,     Up,     Up      ]   };
    key <AC01> {    [     a, A, Left,   Left,   Left    ]   };
    key <AC02> {    [     s, S, Down,   Down,   Down    ]   };
    key <AC03> {    [     d, D, Right,  Right,  Right   ]   };
};
```

The line `include "level5(lsgt_switch)"` works as expected as far as I understand. Because when I open xev and press  key, xev shows

```
KeyPress event, serial 39, synthetic NO, window 0x6c00001,
    root 0x1cd, subw 0x6c00002, time 3942649, (45,46), root:(639,355),
    state 0x0, keycode 94 (keysym 0xfe11, ISO_Level5_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

That I interpret as the key is sending `ISO_Level5_Shift`.

The next four lines implement WASD keys' third, fourth and fifth symbols as arrow keys. However, when I load this and press <LSGT>+W keys, I get 'w' instead of the up arrow key function.

What is the problem here and how to implement this functionality?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding `key.type[Group1] = "EIGHT_LEVEL";` after lsgt switch line. The resulting code is:

```
default partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "berdan" {

    include "us(basic)"
    name[Group1]= "English (Berdan)";

    // Switch ESC with Caps Lock
    key <CAPS>  {   [  Escape       ]   };
    key <ESC>   {   [ Caps_Lock     ]   };

    // Implement LSGT+WASD as arrow buttons
    include "level5(lsgt_switch)"
    key.type[Group1] = "EIGHT_LEVEL";

    key <AD02> {    [     w, W, Up,     Up,     Up      ]   };
    key <AC01> {    [     a, A, Left,   Left,   Left    ]   };
    key <AC02> {    [     s, S, Down,   Down,   Down    ]   };
    key <AC03> {    [     d, D, Right,  Right,  Right   ]   };
};
```